# Script to Download & Resize Image from Remote Server

Tags: php, image-processing, webserver, remote-server

I'm looking for a way to make a web server cache and provide resized images from another remote server.

Let's say there's Site A located somewhere in Africa. On Site A are JPEG images that are refreshed every five minutes (they're webcams). If you visit Site A from the US, the images take quite a while to load since the server is in Africa.

I have Site B. I would like Site B to display the four images from Site A, but I would like them to be served from a server here in the US (which is also where Site B is hosted). That way, they'll, of course, load much quicker.

I'm not familiar with script creation. I tried a few PHP scripts from CodeCanyon and the concept works, but there always seems to be a few minor bugs that cause the entire system to fail.

They work by providing the remote image URL after the local site URL (i.e. http://www.SiteB.com/image_cacher.php?=http://www.SiteA.com/image1.jpg). That's exactly what I want to do.

I'd like the cached images to be stored on the Site B server in a folder called "cache." That way, I can use a cron job to automatically delete the cached images every five minutes; the same frequency the webcam images are updated.

I've solved the cron job issue though, so my only dilemma now is creating some type of script (preferably PHP) that can achieve this.

There are many similar questions like this here, but they're all minutely different and I unfortunately haven't been able to find anything that can perform this task.

Thanks!

Comment: Large-scale sites can make use of CDN's to do this - I'm presuming this is a small-scale project? geo-ip might be your answer as you need to know where on earth the user is!

Comment: Do you need to resize images on the fly? or just copy images from server A?

Comment: This is indeed a small-scale project. However, I don't believe a CDN would even work as the images need to be refreshed every five minutes.

Comment: The images do need to be resized and cached on the fly. Copying the images from Server A to Server would work, but it needs to be automated. Perhaps an "image downloading" script could be a possibility?